# Nested Linq conversion (select)

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to convert an object (Lead) to a reduced form of the same object (ApiLead)
The object contains a list of objects (OtherInHousehold) which also needs to be reduced (ApiOtherInHousehold):

```
result = leads.Select(lead => new ApiLead()
{
    UserId = lead.UserId,
    DepartmentId = lead.DepartmentId,
    CompanyId = lead.CompanyId,
    CPR_number = lead.CPR_number,
    CVR_number = lead.CVR_number,
    Name = (lead.FirstName == "[virksomhed]" ? "" : lead.FirstName + " ") + lead.LastName,
    Address = (lead.Street + " " + lead.StreetNumber + " " + lead.Floor + " " + lead.Side).Trim(),
    Zipcode = lead.Zipcode,
    City = (lead.PlaceName + " " + lead.City).Trim(),
    Phonenumber = ("Fastnet: " + lead.Phonenumber + " Mobil: " + lead.Cellphonenumber),
    Email = lead.Email,
    BestReached = lead.BestReached,
    **OthersInHousehold = lead.OthersInHousehold.Select(oih => new ApiOtherInHousehold(){ CPR_number = oih.CPR_number, Name = oih.Name }).ToList()**,
    WantsVisit = lead.WantsVisit,
    WantsPhonecall = lead.WantsPhonecall,
    WantsInsuranceImmediately = lead.WantsInsuranceImmediately,
    ExistingInsurance = lead.ExistingInsurance,
    CurrentInsuranceCompany = lead.CurrentInsuranceCompany,
    OtherInfo = lead.OtherInfo,
    Status = lead.Status,
    CreationDate = lead.CreationDate
}).ToList();
```

But this throws an

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<LeadsApp.ApiModels.ApiLead>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.List<LeadsApp.Models.Lead>'
```

Is this not possible or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: What is the declaration type of result variable ?

Comment: It's List<Lead> result

Comment: You will have to write code for conversion of ApiLead to Lead. It will not magically happen.

Comment: And that is the answer of your question. At the linq statement, you are returning List<ApiLead>. But result variable is List<Lead>.

Comment: By the way: It's the '**OthersInHousehold = lead.OthersInHousehold.Select(oih => new ApiOtherInHousehold(){ CPR_number = oih.CPR_number, Name = oih.Name }).ToList()**' line that's giving me trouble.

Comment: Again, miss matching types, OthersInHousehold should be declared as ApiOtherInHousehold.

Comment: This is where a [mcve] would make things much, much clearer. Most of the code provided is irrelevant, but there isn't enough to make the problem clear.

Comment: My god, Berkay - so obvious. Thanks a million!!! :D

Comment: Your welcome @ThomasNørgaard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the linq statement, you are returning `List<ApiLead>`. But result variable is `List<Lead>`. You have to declare your result variable as `List<ApiLead>`.

Hope helps,